# Mocking getActionBar() returns null

Tags: java, android, mockito, robolectric

I'm testing an activity, and I want to mock `getActionBar()`. I've tried doing it the usual way, that is

```
ActionBar mActionBar;

@Before
public void setup() {
    initMocks(this);
    mActionBar = Mockito.mock(ActionBar.class);   
}

@Test 
public void someTest(){
    when(activity.getActionBar()).thenReturn(mActionBar);
}
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything, because I still get an NPE, when I try using the action bar in the activity after `getActionBar()`.

Comment: When asking questions, and you get an exception, always also show where this happens in the code.   I've posted an answer though as I'm guessing you just didn't mock enough.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably calling other methods on the mocked `ActionBar` in the code you are testing, like for example:

```
Tab tab = actionBar.getSelectedTab()
```

This returns `null`.  Using `tab` then will result in a NPE.

This means you will need to mock more, for example:

```
when(actionBar.getSelectedTab()).thenReturn(mock(Tab.class));
```

Now the above example will return a mocked `Tab`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're setting `Activity` as it is written in **Robolectric** tutorial. There is no simple way to mock real activity method inside of activity code itself.

I would suggest you create `TestMyActivity` that extends your activity and lives only in test sources. Then you can override `getActionBar()` (probably `getSupportActionBar()`)).

```
public class TestMyActivity extends MyActivity {
   @Override
   ActionBar getActionBar() {
      return mockedActionBar;
   }
}
```